# Looking for a book about people who were taken from different times and escape to the modern world

Tags: story-identification

I can't remember the title to the book but it was about these guys who had been taken from different time lines and thrown into a nether world of sorts. They all had escaped and were in the modern world fighting to make sure they weren't found and taken back. I do remember that the main guy in the first book had been an Ostrogoth his name starts with an O and he uses rune stones.

Comment: Can you add any more details, such as when you read the book, what language it was in, etc.

Comment: Never mind I found it finally, it barbarian by Ewing Lynne

Comment: When you find it, rather than editing your question to include the information, report it as an actual answer to your question. It makes it clear that the search has been 'solved' for others that come looking.

Answer (score 6):

As per the link from that the OP put in his answer

> Title: [Barbarian](https://bepl.ent.sirsi.net/client/en_US/default/search/detailnonmodal/ent:$002f$002fSD_ILS$002f0$002fSD_ILS:1312570/ada)
>   Author: Ewing, Lynne.
>   Series: Sons of the dark ; 1
>   Summary: Having escaped from Nefandus, a parallel universe where he was made an immortal slave, fifteen-year-old Obie must return to retrieve his mother's rune stones in order to fulfill his destiny in modern-day Los Angeles as one of the four Sons of the Dark.